# Read more break only showing from the dashboard — Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

sorry to bother with this super silly question but I can't find anyone else reporting this. When I insert a more break in a post on Tumblr, it shows it in my dashboard but it's nowhere to be seen on the actual post. 
Moreover, the regular more break doesn't seem to work properly, even if others say that at least that one should work, if the [[MORE]] fails. more is ignored both with and without the paragraph tag. Since I've had issues with the updating in Chrome before, I've tried re editing the post also with Opera and Firefox, but no luck. 
Does anyone know what should I be looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a link to the post? This is more than likely the theme remove the Read More anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Read More is meant to shorten a post on your dashboard so that it doesn't clog it if the content in the post is long. The reason why it doesn't show on the actual post on your blog theme is because when you click the Read More, it shows all the content under the Read More, but the Read More is gone. See what I mean?

In order to make the [[MORE]] work, it has to be inside of the "p" paragraph divs like this:

```
<p>[[MORE]]</p>
```

But you only insert that in the HTML section of the post. If you don't know where this section is, it is located on the very end of the edit bar when you are creating/editing a post (like where the Bold, Italic, Blockquote button, Read More button, etc are at.